# Imprimir HTML div en vez de Popup

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Deseo saber si hay cómo imprimir un `div` con texto en vez de un `popup` desde AngularJS hacia la vista HTML.

Para que me puedan entender mejor este es mi código:

```
ServCompEdu.servicioCompEdu($scope.cedula).success(function(data){
    $scope.datosComp=data;    
  })
  .error(function(data){
    // Enves de este popup quiero imprimir algo como esto <p>Error al obtener los componentes educativos<p>
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'Error al obtener los componentes educativos'
    });
  })
```

Esta es mi vista HTML:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<ion-view view-title="Componentes">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="list card">
      <div class="item item-input-inset">
        <label class="item-input-wrapper">
           <h4>
             PERÍODO ACADÉMICO: Oct/2015 - Feb/2016
          </h4>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list card">
      <ion-list>
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="i in datosComp">
          <div class="col col-20" >
              <div ng-repeat="x in i.paralelos">
                <a ng-click="info(i.nom_coe,x.paralelo,i.creditos,x.dia,x.hora_inicio,x.hora_fin)"
                   class="circulo">
                  {{ i.nom_coe | limitTo:1 }}
                </a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col col-80">
            <ion-item type="item-text-wrap" href="#/Gtuto/componentes/{{i.nom_coe}}">
              <h3>{{i.nom_coe}}</h3>
              <h5 ng-repeat="x in i.paralelos">PARALELO: <strong>{{x.paralelo}}</strong></h5>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>//Aqui deseo imprimir el error(etiqueta P)</ion-item>
          </div>          
        </div>  
      </ion-list>
    </div> 
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Realmente lo que deseo es imprimir en esta vista el error de mi AngularJS.

Comment: Porque usas `promise.success(function).fail(function)`? Si estas usando ionic y angular deberias usar `promise.then(function, function)`

Comment: Creo que deberias tambíen usar [`collection-repeat`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/) en lugar de `ng-repeat`. Este es básicamente lo mismo pero está optimizado para móviles y collecciones largas de datos que tendrían un impacto negativo cuando se renderizen en un webview nativo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que quieres lograr es sencillo. Sólo usa una variable en el scope y un simple binding para el error y muestrala solamente cuando sea distinto de cadena vacía.

*controller*

```
$scope.errorEducativo = '';

ServCompEdu.servicioCompEdu($scope.cedula).success(function(data){
    $scope.datosComp=data;    
})
.error(function(data){
    $scope.errorEducativo = 'Error al obtener los componentes educativos';
});
```

*vista*

```
<ion-list>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="i in datosComp">
        <div class="col col-20" >
           <div ng-repeat="x in i.paralelos">
              <a class="circulo" ng-click="info(i.nom_coe,x.paralelo,i.creditos,x.dia,x.hora_inicio,x.hora_fin)">
                  {{ i.nom_coe | limitTo:1 }}
              </a>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-80">
            <ion-item type="item-text-wrap" href="#/Gtuto/componentes/{{i.nom_coe}}">
                <h3>{{i.nom_coe}}</h3>
                <h5 ng-repeat="x in i.paralelos">PARALELO: <strong>{{x.paralelo}}</strong></h5>
            </ion-item>
            <!-- Este item solo se muestra si hay un error -->
            <ion-item ng-show="errorEducativo">
                {{errorEducativo}}
            </ion-item>
        </div>          
    </div>  
</ion-list>
```

Recuerda agregar una condición para resetear el valor de `errorEducativo` a cadena vacía en caso que estes usando un formulario para entrar datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte amigo....Me ha servido de mucho :D :D :D

Comment: Quiero agregar que *no es recomendable* usar un `ion-item` para mostrar un error. `ion-item` es una unidad individual de contenido dentro de una lista y por lo tanto se *debe usar* para eso mismo. El error siempre está relacionado con alguien así que es recomendable que lo pongas dentro del `ion-item` que generó el error. Esto es una recomendación de diseño asi que no es obligatoria. También decirte que `ion-item` debe ser descendiente directo de `ion-list`. Creo que debes reestructurar el `grid` para que se ajuste a esto. No sé lo que estás haciendo por lo que no puedo aportar más. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Es posible pasarle a [`$ionicPopup.alert()`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/#alert) otros parámetros para customizar el diseño.

Puedes usar el parámetro `template` para pasarle código HTML como una cadena de texto:

```
var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
  title: 'Error',
  template: '<p>Error al obtener los componentes educativos<p>'
});
```

También es posible pasarle la URL de un template para renderizar el cuerpo del Popup:

```
var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
  title: 'Error',
  templateUrl: 'templates/error.html'
});
```

El código HTML iría entonces en el template `error.html`.